# 3d Grease pencil fill

Tags: grease-pencil

When drawing in a 3d space with grease pencil, is there a way to fill a curved / endless plane. for example, If I draw a rectangle, with 2 square corners on one end and a radius on the other. And then Duplicate and drag over.  is it possible to fill The gap between the 2 grease pencil objects? I have not yet found if this is possible.

Comment: With the help of Animation Nodes, you can convert any 3D-mesh object to 3D-grease pencil object i.e., faces to fill and edges to stroke lines.

Comment: Oh cool! I am familiar with animation nodes, have even done a tutorial or 2 of yours, thank you btw. How would I achieve this through animation nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert **any Mesh object to 3D Grease Pencil object** we need Animation Nodes with Extra Nodes(Builds available for [Linux](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/tdbbbc/), [Windows](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/xdbbbc/)),

**(1)** First we have to get all the individual polygon (face) vertices using Mesh Object Node and Separate Polygons Node. Separate Polygons Node is needed because all
polygons are joined i.e., they are sharing some vertices,

[image]

**(2)** then convert a polygon vertices to a close (cyclic) grease pencil stroke with fill using GPencil Stroke Output Node.

**(3)** Because a mesh has many polygons (faces) so we are going to use the Loop Group Node (Loop Input) to convert all polygons to fill grease pencil strokes (cyclic).

[image]

**(4)** Now we have all strokes as output from the Loop Node, with GPencil Object Output Node we can convert them to a grease pencil object.

[image]

Happy Noding :)

Comment: I have tested it yesterday on Linux with the latest Blender 2.8 build and it is working. AN+Extra nodes build is available for Linux and Windows on the Graphicall (Links in the answer are updated). You have to install AN+Extra nodes build according to your OS. Can tell which OS you are using?

Comment: @NickSieben I think AN is not installed properly or not the latest one. Both links are different, there is a "Download" option just below the title. Anyway, download the AN + Extra Nodes build (a zip file) from https://blender.community/5cfab37c5996560ea6ced2e7/download/5cfab3e25996560ed2b774d4 and then rename it as "AnimationNodes". Remove the existing AN and install this new AN. Let me know if it works.

Comment: No, this is the correct version of python which is needed for latest Blender 2.8x. Are you still getting the error message in AN?

Comment: That download button is so small I never even noticed it! this works perfectly thank you!